# Phone says it's unable to conference calls

Tags: cyanogenmod, calls

I'd like to do a conference call with my Android phone (running Cyanogenmod 7).  I call one number, then call another.  Then I press "Merge calls", but the phone gives the message "unable to conference calls".  Why would this be?  Interestingly, this doesn't always happen.  Sometimes it succeeds, and gives me a conference call with a "Manage" icon in the middle.  So, why would it sometimes fail?

Comment: Is the message on the phone or threw the speaker (ie is it the android OS that is telling you it failed or a recorded message?) If it is the latter then it is likely a restriction enforced by you provider.

Comment: It's on the phone screen, in a popup.